# unable to count the exact number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written a model code where i am joining two tables, and returning my results.

From the below table structure my model code is showing only  2 question count, skipping the last question, After little research i found the reason why it is not counting my third question, it is because it does not have any answer in my `answer` table.

I want, if no answer then it should show count=0 for the particular question, How can to solve this issue?

Table structure

```
question
-----------
question_id PK Auto_Incr  
question    varchar... 
votes       int


answer
------------
answer_id    PK  Auto_icre
question_id  FK refrences question  
content      longtext
```

---

Table Data structure data:

```
 question
-----------
 question_id    question          votes
    1           what's name?       0
    2           where you?         3
    3           blah blah          9 

answer 
----------
 answer_id      question_id        content
    4              2                 India
    5              2                 Nepal
    6              2                 Pakistan
    7              1                 Mr Osama Binladan
```

---

Model

```
public function fetch_allquestions($limit, $start) 
{
    $this->load->database(); 
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);   
    $this->db->from('question');
    $select =array(
                   'question.*',
                   'userdetails.*',
                   'COUNT(answer.answer_id) AS `Answers`'
                  );

    $this->db->select($select);

    $this->db->join('answer','answer.question_id = question.question_id'); 
    $this->db->join('userdetails','userdetails.user_id = question.user_id'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    print_r("Number of rows=".$query->num_rows());//showing only One, out of 26 rows

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, Thankyou.Working fine. I did not know that. What does it mean by left in this join?   Post it as answer with litle explanation. So that i can accept your answer

Comment: @BurlsWillis MySQL `LEFT JOIN`, ready the [documentation about it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/left-join-optimization.html).

Comment: @BurlsWillis Sure, added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_joins), which basically means that if there is a row in the table mentioned first exists, a corresponding row in the second table mentioned is not required. In your case, if there's a question, it will be returned even if there is no matching answer.

To do a left join in codeigniter, you can just pass 'left' as a third parameter to your call to `join`;

```
$this->db->join('answer','answer.question_id = question.question_id', 'left');
```

More info on the join call is available [at the CodeIgniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use LEFT join

```
$this->db->join('answer','answer.question_id = question.question_id','LEFT');
```